# Yun as bluetooth master

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-yun

How does one make an outgoing bluetooth connection?  I have already installed packages for bluetooth, and have run `hcitool scan` to find the BT address. And I'm using a USB BT dongle.

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
```

Comment: Outgoing connection to *what*?

Comment: what connects matters?

Comment: Yes, it matters. You use different commands to configure different kinds of connections.  Bluetooth is a vast topic, so you *have* to be specific or we'll be here for the next month.

Comment: I'm trying to stream audio from an sd card to a headset

Comment: @Majenko Is generic pairing instructions possible?

Comment: No, as I said you use different commands for different devices.  I don't have BT on my Yún at the moment to play, but this may help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96693/connect-to-a-bluetooth-device-via-terminal

Comment: @Majenko No Bluez-tools for yun... :(

Comment: There's "bluez-utils" - have you looked at that?  Different package systems name things differently.

Comment: Also, in my experience, getting bluetooth audio to work on Linux has meant integration with Pulse Audio, which I doubt you'll have on the Yùn.